# How to heal a flapper quickly

Tags: rock-climbing, climbing, bouldering

I've noticed when climbing and bouldering I have a tendency to get occasional flappers on my palm. A flapper being a callus or blister that has peeled back and hangs on like a flap of skin. I trim the skin away as close to the origin as possible to avoid having it snag on anything, it then tends to take a couple weeks to heal completely, though by the first week it's usually healed enough to climb without major inconvenience.

Are there any tricks other people have to healing a flapper quicker?

Comment: I would say that the trick is more avoiding getting them in the first place.  I have an answer about this a while ago that you may want to look up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides super glue, as some do not want to go that route, here is another option.

You also mentioned that you cut it off. This can actually slow the healing process as it will dry out the skin underneath the flapper. The best solution I found and experienced was to clean up the wound, which will hurt at first but is necessary, and then leave the skin overtop the open underlayer of skin.

The idea to promote healing is to keep the moisture in and protect it from infection and further damage. If the flapper is damaged and should not be placed back, then carefully cut it off and use a moisture pad like 2nd Skin or even a bandaid that seals the tear.

Links that support leaving the flap on and moisture to help with healing:

- [Skin tear treatment 1](https://advancedtissue.com/2015/11/skin-tears-common-treatment-approaches-and-protocols/)
- [Skin tear treatment 2](https://www.healthline.com/health/skin-tear#care-and-treatment)

Also, if you feel like you are getting to the point of a flapper, a preventative measure is to file it (or, what I do, sand it with a Dremmel) down and stop climbing. Let the skin heal stronger and use a skin strengthening balm like Climb-on or similar.

Comment: I would be more comfortable with this answer as it actually covers this type of injury specifically.

Comment: I would also recommend moisturising your hands a couple of hours before climbing. It makes the pads healthy and supple, ready to take the harsh punishment. You want your calluses tough but flexible, like a dogs paw pads.

Answer (score 1):

## Super Glue...

Instead of cutting the flap of skin off, glue it back down with super glue.

There is a plethora of blog posts about it.

There are specific formulias for medical usage

> For your first aid kit:
>
> 2-Octyl-cyanoacrylate
>
> - Dermabond
> - SurgiSeal
>
> N-2-butyl-cyanoacrylate
>
> - Histoacryl
> - Indermil
> - GluStitch
> - GluSeal
> - LiquiBand
>
> 2-Ethyl-cyanoacrylate
>
> - Epiglu

[Source](https://www.healthline.com/health/super-glue-on-cuts)

Comment: This should come with a warning though, superglue bonds skin instantly, accidentally gluing your hands together and making even more of a mess is really easily done.

Comment: @Separatrix the medical grade ones include directions. Different types have different drying times. Addressing the variables is beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: As stated in your source. do not use on mobile skin such as around joints. In my experience this is where I most often have these kinds of wounds. I'd suggest including those warnings in your answer!

Comment: I mentioned leaving the skin on but I didn't mention glue. I am aware of the glue method as well, but you need to be careful which one you use as some are toxic and will be absorbed, especially on the sensitive layers of skin below the flapper.